# How do i duplicate to get the same size on all corners of the objects?

Tags: dupli-groups

[image][image][image][image]I am creating landing feet for my space craft and when i do it manualy and as you can see from the picture if i do this manualy by creating a cube cutting eachcorner i cant seem to get the cut's exactly identical on all sides is there anyway i can do it for one corner and one click duplicate for all corners, do's blender have this functionality so i am not getting fustrated by the end product not being right in dimension'senter image description here? :)

Answer (score 6):

Select all of the side faces of a cube (excluding top and bottom) and do **Extrude individual**

[image]

To scale the newly created faces, just press <kbd>S</kbd> (to scale) and constraint the scaling to the X and Y axes by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd> or checking the X and Y boxes on the tool panel.

[image]

Comment: Hi thanky ou for this :) I do like this one the best as it is the easiest however the retangualrs are a bit traingler :) i have posted a picture of what i want above :)

Comment: See edited answer

Comment: Hi I trieds the extruding and got the above result ( please see picture above of what i get ) it wont let me just select the sides of the cube, how are you selecting just the sides of the cube? obviously as i am new it is something i am not doing right :) thanks for your patience.

Comment: @SimonBlender: You switch to Face select mode. See that three-part selector at the bottom of the screenshot? Hit the third one (with the face (side) icon).

Comment: Thanks buddy :) all done and it looks awesome and it looks amazingly lovely :) i did it as a trioal seperate from my main project when i get home later tonight i shall apply this to my main project tah very much :)

Answer (score 4):

Start with a plane and a mirror modifier, set the modifier to use X and Y and then you can position your plane to be oriented off center with the corner at the object origin (or you can just loopcut and delete the parts you don't need). You can then extrude and model with the parts being the same in both directions.[image]

Comment: Hummm interesting thank for this i shall try this way to as i want to learn as much as i can, i have only just started using blender 6-7 weeks ago :) could i ask the feet are triangular is there a way to distort them to get them like the new picture i have posted above?

Comment: i think it's a little complicated this way :D

Comment: This answer accounts for when you need to add extra geometry and cannot use the other method. Learn both.